# Get Root NodeRef Alfresco REST

Tags: rest, alfresco

I'm looking to find the 'root' nodeRef of Alfresco using REST.
I'm using an Alfresco v5.1.

If anyone could help me on this it would be great, thanks in advance =)

(NOTE : I call the 'root' the folder where are stored 'Sites', etc ...)

EDIT : Found out that the 'root' folder is called 'Company Home'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get children or property of node or all the nodes of root,this link will guide you How to get.
https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/blog/2016/10/17/v1-rest-api-part-2-navigation.

https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/listNodeChildren

Comment: Sadly, this API is valable only for Alfresco v5.2. Mine is still 5.1 :/

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to get it with :

/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser

body contains the rootNodeRef =)

Comment: it was rootFolderId for my case